# how to solve result from raw expression query builder in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get the result as just

> 100.0%

in Laravel blade.php? When I use code raw expression in laravel 5.5 below:

```
$jml_status_ap_all_pr =DB::table('aps')->select(DB::raw('ROUND((COUNT(STATUS)/(SELECT
COUNT(*) FROM aps))*100,1) as calc'))->get();
```

I get this result:

> [{"calc":"100.0"}] %

in blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->get()` method of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` return instance of `\Illuminate\Support\Collection`, In your case need get only one result. For this use `->first() method instead of ->get()`. `->first()` method return instance of `stdClass` and you can directly get your needed attribute

For your case corrected code is.

```
$jml_status_ap_all_pr = DB::table('aps')
    ->select(DB::raw('ROUND((COUNT(STATUS)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aps))*100,1) as calc'))
    ->first()
    ->calc;
```

Comment: i got error  Exception
Property [calc] does not exist on this collection instance. when i use 'calc'

Comment: What is result. It is your expected result ??