# Max() with different label array

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code for function, each variable has different label with array: I want to find max value from this code.

```
      $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $first_hour = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as first'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '01:00:00')"))
        ->first();

    $last_hour = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as last'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw('exchanges.close_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw("SUBTIME(exchanges.close_time, '01:00:00')"))
        ->first();


    $other_hours = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as other'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereRaw('finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.start_time AND DATE_ADD(exchanges.start_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')
        ->whereRaw('finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.close_time AND DATE_SUB(exchanges.close_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')
        ->first();


    $allTrades = array($first_hour,  $last_hour,$other_hours );
    $max =0;
    Foreach($allTrades as $key => $val){
        $temp = max($val);
        If($temp > $max){
            $max = $temp;
            $place = $key . " => " . Key($val);
        }
    }

    Echo $max;
    Echo "\n" . $place;
```

How to get max value from this type of array in arrays?
Every array has different name : first, last and other

this is result of `variable`:

[image]

Comment: We need to see the variables, we can't run your database code

Comment: You want to see result of `$variable`? @Andreas you can connect my laptop?

Comment: No I will not. I just want to see the variables

Comment: I posted image @Andreas

Comment: If that is your array then this code should work. It's an exact copy of your array. https://3v4l.org/8m45b don't know why it should not work

Comment: i dont know but this is not working@Andreas let me try again.

Comment: Your array element is not an array they is object of std class. see my answer

Comment: @Davit I am trying to understand `your code` which has excellent logic.

Comment: Are you know about how to work **Builder** instance?? And how to get object properties??

Comment: I am watching tutorial about `Query builder`. But its too difficult for me because, I am newbie.@Davit. I want to learn `laravel relationship` also.

Comment: See my other answer about Query builder [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788126/how-to-solve-result-from-raw-expression-query-builder-in-laravel-5-5/50788185#50788185](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788126/how-to-solve-result-from-raw-expression-query-builder-in-laravel-5-5/50788185#50788185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use corected code

```
$allTrades = array($first_hour,  $last_hour,$other_hours );
$max = 0;
$property = '';

foreach ($allTrades as $stdObject) {
    $propertyValues = get_object_vars($stdObject);
    foreach ($propertyValues as $prop => $value) {
        if ($value > $max) {
            $max = $value;
            $property = $prop;
        }
    }
}

echo $max;
echo $property;
```

or one step less if know $first_hour object structure

```
$allTrades = array($last_hour,$other_hours );
$max = $first_hour->first;
$property = 'first';

foreach ($allTrades as $stdObject) {
    $propertyValues = get_object_vars($stdObject);
    foreach ($propertyValues as $prop => $value) {
        if ($value > $max) {
            $max = $value;
            $property = $prop;
        }
    }
}
echo $max;
echo $property;
```

Comment: Perfect worked! I have thumb up for you. Someone sent me down thumb... I will learn form your code. @Davit

Answer (score 0):

Use this, just compare every new value with previous one and change variables' values if required:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$first_hour = DB::table('finaltrade')
    // 
    ->first();

$max = $first_hour['first'];
$key = 'first';

$last_hour = DB::table('finaltrade')
    // 
    ->first();

if ($last_hour['last'] > $max) {
    $max = $last_hour['last'];
    $key = 'last';
}

$other_hours = DB::table('finaltrade')
    // 
    ->first();

if ($other_hours['other'] > $max) {
    $max = $other_hours['other'];
    $key = 'other';
}
```

Comment: yes I done this, when i try `DD($max);`, its again give me wrong result.

Comment: Check the update, as result of each query is __array__, you need to compare values under certain keys, not arrays itself.

Comment: How can you help me how to compare keys? I have added your code.

Comment: See my answer please, do you see `[]` there?

Comment: I have pasted but its till give me result : `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array `... end of all `DD($max);`

Comment: Then use `->` notation. `->last`, `->first`.

Comment: when i tiree with `last()`, then generate : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::last()`

Comment: Not method, property. Do you know the difference?

Comment: I am `newbie`, try to learn with my project. I will not leave what i have started.

Comment: i can send you every result what you asked, but i don;t want to leave this today.

Comment: Please, open a manual. Getting property of an object is done with `->last` __without `()`__.